# How can I restore the back button functionality in UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have created my own leftBarButtonItem:

```
UIBarButtonItem* homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks 
                                                                                    target:self 
                                                                                    action:@selector(homeButtonClicked:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = homeButton;
```

How can I restore the original back button functionality programmatically?

Comment: You should really change your accepted answer. pgb's solution doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The back button will call `UINavigationController`'s `popViewController`, so you can replicate that on your `homeButtonClicked:` selector.

Answer (score 38):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: This is actually the answer I was looking for - I don't know why it was rated down!

Comment: This is not the answer to the actual question. But it is what I was searching for.

Answer (score 4):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

This will remove your custom left button, and the back button will appear again.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for :)